# Divide contents of folder into separate folders

Tags: split, action, directory, automator

I have a folder with 518 .tcx files in it. I would like to upload those gps files to Strava.com. Strava only allows for bulk uploads of 25 files at a time.

I have a folder with 518 files. I would like to divide those to bite-sized pieces (25 files) then upload them via an email uploading option that Strava offers.

I was thinking automator could help, but I can't find anything like that. I would also like to offer this as a solution for other people switching to Strava from Garmin and I thought it would be easy to offer it as an automator action.

Suggestions?

-Josh

Comment: What environment (Windows, CygWin, Mac, Linux, other) is this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Automator itself doesn’t have a straightforward way to divide input into chunks that I’m aware of.  However, that’s part of what `xargs`(1) is designed to do.

1. Make a normal workflow with a “New Mail Message” action, and fill it out as you need.  If you’re feeling confident, follow it with a “Send Outgoing Messages” action.  (For the purposes of these steps, save it in your home folder as “send-files.workflow”.)
2. Make a Service workflow (receives selected documents in Finder) with this action:

   Run Shell Script (Shell: /bin/bash, Pass input: to stdin)

   ```
   xargs -n 25 automator -i - ~/send-files.workflow
   ```

You can now select a mess of files and select your service, which will create Mail messages containing batches of (up to) 25 of them.  Obviously, if you’re comfortable with Terminal, you could do step 2 directly from the command line instead of using a service, like this:

```
ls *.tcx | xargs -n 25 -i - ~/send-files.workflow
```

Also, a little known fact: if you open a file with Mail, it will create a new message with that file as an enclosure.  If you open multiple files in one shot, it will create a single message with all of them, so you can do something like this:

```
ls *.tcx | xargs -n 25 open -a Mail
```

Of course, this only creates a message with the enclosures, it doesn’t address or send it for you, but it’s useful for one-shot tasks.